# jQuery $.ajax() call to get JSON from Rails 3 controller results in 304 Not Modified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In application.js I have:

```
$("#combo_box").live('change', (function() {
    $.ajax( {
                    url: '/my_controller/get_data',
                    data: {id: some_id},
                    success:  function(data){ do_stuff_with_data(data) }
             }
           )
    } ) )
```

and in my_controller code I have:

```
  def get_data
    id = params[:id]

    @data = MyModel.DoSomeStuff(id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => @data}
    end
  end
```

But for some reason the function in `success` is only run once (I think) and the rest of the times Firebug reports a `304 Not Modified` when the combo box change triggers an ajax call.

How does that work? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default method for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is GET:

> **type** String
>   Default: 'GET'

so your `$.ajax` call is doing a GET request and someone is probably caching it. Try adding `cache: false` to your `$.ajax` options:

> **cache** Boolean
>   Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>   If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.

Comment: I didn't realize that the browser was caching the get, very interesting, that did the trick!

Comment: Also I wanted to point out that jQuery was returning the result as a string until I specifically set dataType: 'json' in the ajax call, that threw me off for a while.