# how to use a pass a jquery variable to rails html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

how can i pass a jquery variable to a rails function in html. Here is what i want to accomplish:

```
<%= select_tag :teams, options_from_collection_for_select(Fteam.all, "id", "Team") %>
```

The selection from above gets put into a textbox here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#teams').change(function(){
   $(this).val() != "" ? $('#myTextBox2').val($(this).val()) : $('#myTextBox2').hide();
});
});
```

How to i get it into this rails function below:

```
<select id = "test3" style= float:right>
<% Teamplayer.find_each(:conditions => :teamid => '#myTextBox2') do |tp| %>
    <option> <%=teamplayer.id %></option>
    <option>Players on team 1</option>
<% end %>
```

You see where in the find_each i am trying to put the value. I need the value to go from the textbox to to the find_each function so i can pull down the matching records from the database.

Comment: For such behavior you need to create method in your controller which responds to js request and return the `TeamPlayer` objects, which then can be read by your `$.ajax(..)` call when event is successful.

Comment: i thought ajax was for posting to another webpage. The jquery is in a header.html.erb file. So how can i save it to the controller then have the index.html.erb page use that variable?

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947878/jquery-ajax-call-to-get-json-from-rails-3-controller-results-in-304-not-modi